# How to map rest controller and angularjs, spring

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, rest

I have filepaths stored in scope variable(an array) of AngularJs Controller.

I want to map it to java rest controller for further processing.

If I pass it like "/ABC/Scope-Variable" it matches the rest controller by taking Scope-Variable as String

But if i use "/ABC/+Scope-Variable" , I Guess Since file path has Slash(/) and also an array, i am not able to map to the java rest controller.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create proper controller in Spring.

**SpringController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class SpringController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateItems", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ArrayList<String> updateItems(@RequestBody List<String> updatedItems) {
       System.out.println(updatedItems);
       // do sth
       return null;
    }
}
```

Then, in your JavaScript file you do something like that:

**AngularFile.js:**

```
$scope.items = ['path1.jpg', 'path2.jpg', 'path3.jpg'];
$http.post('http://server:port/updateItems', $scope.items).success(function(response) {
        console.log('posted items!');
});
```